# Duplicate array elements in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates, element

I have an array `rangers = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black"]` *(it's debatable that green should part of it, but I decided to omitted it)*

I want to double the array elements so it returns `rangers = ["red", "red", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "pink", "pink", "black", "black"]` in that order.

I tried look around SO, but I could not find find a way to do it in that order. (`rangers *= 2` won't work).

I have also tried `rangers.map{|ar| ar * 2} #=> ["redred", "blueblue",...]`

I tried `rangers << rangers #=> ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black", [...]]`

How can I duplicate elements to return the duplicate element value right next to it? Also, if possible, I would like to duplicate it *n* times, so when `n = 3`, it returns `["red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", ...]`

Comment: The green ranger **is** the best one, though. ;P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
rangers.zip(rangers).flatten
```

using [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten)?

A solution that might generalize a bit better for your second request might be:

```
rangers.flat_map { |ranger| [ranger] * 2 }
```

using [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).
Here you can just replace the `2` with any value or variable.

Comment: also: `([rangers]*n).inject(&:zip).flatten` :)

Comment: Oh, very nice @MladenJablanović. ;)

Comment: Very convenient! I didn't think of using zip + flatten combo. Will prove very handy in the future. Thanks all!

Comment: @MladenJablanović even better in my opinion though: `([rangers] * n).transpose.flatten`. This question really inspires me. x)

Comment: This card allows you to go directly to `flat_map` without passing `map` (I.e. no reason to mention `map`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I thought you might say something like that. ;)